Opcache.php return an empty page
We are using PHP + FPM 8.2 + OPCache. In the past, we use https://www.repairrar.com/opcache.php to check its status. But today it returns an empty page. Although it shows an empty page, I view the page source and find its contents are about 3.3MB, but they are just not show in the browser. I tried Chrome and FireFox, but show empty contents.
I also write a small PHP file
<?php
    echo '<pre>' , var_dump(opcache_get_status(false)) , '</pre>';
?>

When visit https://www.repairrar.com/opcache-get-status.php, it shows the OpCache is enabled and performed properly:
array(8) {
  ["opcache_enabled"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["cache_full"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["restart_pending"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["restart_in_progress"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["memory_usage"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["used_memory"]=>
    int(446911376)
    ["free_memory"]=>
    int(626183176)
    ["wasted_memory"]=>
    int(647272)
    ["current_wasted_percentage"]=>
    float(0.0602819025516510009765625)
  }
  ["interned_strings_usage"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["buffer_size"]=>
    int(134217728)
    ["used_memory"]=>
    int(52098200)
    ["free_memory"]=>
    int(82119528)
    ["number_of_strings"]=>
    int(242556)
  }
  ["opcache_statistics"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["num_cached_scripts"]=>
    int(10741)
    ["num_cached_keys"]=>
    int(15444)
    ["max_cached_keys"]=>
    int(130987)
    ["hits"]=>
    int(167134669)
    ["start_time"]=>
    int(1733489514)
    ["last_restart_time"]=>
    int(0)
    ["oom_restarts"]=>
    int(0)
    ["hash_restarts"]=>
    int(0)
    ["manual_restarts"]=>
    int(0)
    ["misses"]=>
    int(11569)
    ["blacklist_misses"]=>
    int(0)
    ["blacklist_miss_ratio"]=>
    float(0)
    ["opcache_hit_rate"]=>
    float(99.99307851607164820961770601570606231689453125)
  }
  ["jit"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["enabled"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["on"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["kind"]=>
    int(5)
    ["opt_level"]=>
    int(4)
    ["opt_flags"]=>
    int(6)
    ["buffer_size"]=>
    int(0)
    ["buffer_free"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}

And below is the php.ini file(I check the change history and it has not be changed since Opcache.php return visible contents):
; cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
; For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 64M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 2880
#session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
upload_max_filesize = 64M
zlib.output_compression = Off
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php82"

; The gloabal 10-opcahce.ini has already enable opcache, so it is not necessary to enable it here again.
; Enable opcache here will cause 'Zend OPcache can't be temporary enabled' warning in PHP. So the following
; line is commented out
; opcache.enable=1



You have a problem with your React javascript files.
When visiting those resources on unpkg, the page shows a 404 for the following:

https://unpkg.com/react-dom@19.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js
https://unpkg.com/react@19.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js

You can verify this by visiting the page on any browser and going to the Console to show the rendering errors. (On Firefox, press F12, go to Console, and look for the red warning errors).
Install those files on your server, link to them instead of using an external site, and the page should render properly.

Thank you very much. The problem is solved by upgrading opcache.php with the latest version.
